# Highcharts API fillColor property not working

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I am having trouble using the fillColor property in the highchairs api. Below is my code. I have tried setting the fillColor property with a rgb value and by setting it equal to a color. For example, I tried fillColor: "blue",. No matter what I try I am not getting any fillColor for my line chart. I am able to change the line color and the color of the markers.

```
<script>
$(function() {
$('#container').highcharts({
credits : {
  enabled: false
},
exporting:
{
  enabled: false
},
  chart: {
      type: 'line'
  },
  title: {
      text: "Progress"
  },
  subtitle: {
      text: 'Village Print & Media'
  },
  xAxis: {
    title:{
        margin: 50,
        text: "February"
    },
    categories: ["2/3", "2/6", "2/9", "2/12", "2/15", "2/18", "2/21", "2/24", "2/27"]
  },
  yAxis: {
      title: {
          text: "Points"
      }
  },

      plotOptions: {

        series: {
        color: "black",
        fillColor: "#00FF00",
        fillOpacity: 0.7,


         },
      line: {
          dataLabels: {
              enabled: false
          },
          enableMouseTracking: true
      }


  },
  legend: {
      layout: 'vertical',
      align: 'left',
      verticalAlign: 'middle',
      borderWidth: 2
  },
  series: [{
      name: 'Points Ray',
      data: [5, 10, 15, 17, 25, 30, 34, 35, 50]
  }]
});
 });
 </script>
```

Comment: There is no fillColor property for a line series (what would it fill?). If you want a filled area, you need to use the **area** series type: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.area

Comment: I changed the chart type to area and it worked. Thank you